# Trying to remote access from windows to ububntu

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop

I'm trying to share the Ubuntu desktop through SSH (my company required it to be through SSH, can't use VNC). I installed xrdp, updated it, enabled it and added firewall rule. Now the nmap command show it listening on 3389 port. This is the nmap localhost command:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-04-07 12:01 IDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

Yet when I'm trying to connect from my windows client, both from the build-in windows remote and from PuTTY they don't find the computer.

I rechecked the IP address and the address is correct.

Anyone knows what can I do?

thanks!

Comment: Hello. what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The default port for ssh is 22 so that needs to be open. However it is possible to configure it to use an other port if you have a reason to do so

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, it looks like you would like to want use xRDP and secure it through SSH tunnels.  You can find detailed information on how to do that at this location ([[xRDP – How to secure Xrdp Connection using SSH Tunnels on Ubuntu 20.04]](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14965))

In a nutshell, you will need to

- install xrdp software on your Ubuntu machine

  **sudo apt-get install xrdp -y**
- Install Open-SSH Server on your Ubuntu machine

  **sudo apt-get install openssh-server**
- Tweak the xrdp.ini file in order to enforce SSH connection through port 3389

  **Replace line in xrdp port=3389 with  port=tcp://.:3389**
- Restart the xrdp service

  **sudo systemctl restart xrdp**

At this stage, your Ubuntu machine is configured accordingly and you are ready to use your favorit SSH client to perform the connection via SSH tunnel

Assuming that you are using the built-in ssh client available on Windows 10, you would connect to your UBuntu machine using a command similar to the one below

```
ssh %user%@%servername-or-ip% -L %LocalPort%:127.0.0.1:%RemotePort%
```

Obviously, you have to replace the %% values with your value and you should be able to login to your Ubuntu Desktop. Hereafter, an example with fake values (just to show the syntax to be used)

**`ex. ssh admin@ubuntu -L5555:127.0.0.1:3389`**

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Comment: Thanks! that was indeed what I was looking for. worked perfectly.